# How to query a firestore database correctly?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I wrote this function which takes in a username and password string. Then it queries the collection of users in a firestore database to see if that username is taken. If the query comes back with any document, it returns and leaves the closure. If it does not find a document, it creates the user with the specified data. The function correctly writes to the database, but the query logic does not work, so multiple users have the same username.

Here is the relevant code associated with the function:

```
func createAccountWith(_ username: String, _ password: String){
    
        let userPath = "users"
        let store = Firestore.firestore()
        let userDB = store.collection(userPath)
        
        
        //Query the DB for the given username. If we find that username, then throw an error
        userDB.whereField("username", isEqualTo: username).getDocuments(){ (querySnapshot, err) in

            if let error = err{
                print("Error querying DB: \(error)")
                return
            }
            
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents{
                if document.exists{
                    return
                }
            }



        }
        
        //set data if no document exists
        userDB.document("\(UUID().uuidString)").setData(
            [
                "username":username,
                "password":password
            ]
        
        )
        
        
    }
```

Comment: The WWDC [async await video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10132) is pretty good at explaining the “old” ways, the new way and how to make closures work with the new way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In async code, it's wrong to think that a line of code that appears before another line *executes* before it.  In the OP case...

```
func createAccountWith(_ username: String, _ password: String){
    
        let userPath = "users"
        let store = Firestore.firestore()
        let userDB = store.collection(userPath)
        
        // *** THIS RUNS FIRST
        //Query the DB for the given username. If we find that username, then throw an error
        userDB.whereField("username", isEqualTo: username).getDocuments(){ (querySnapshot, err) in

            // *** THIS RUNS THIRD, A "LONG TIME" AFTER
            if let error = err{
                print("Error querying DB: \(error)")
                return
            }
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents{
                if document.exists{
                    return
                }
            }

        }
        // *** THIS RUNS SECOND, RIGHT AWAY, BEFORE THE GET COMPLETES
        //set data if no document exists
        userDB.document("\(UUID().uuidString)").setData(
            [
                "username":username,
                "password":password
            ]
        )

    }
```

So to fix, do the user creation inside the closure, after you discover that there's no matching username...

```
func createAccountWith(_ username: String, _ password: String){
    
        let userPath = "users"
        let store = Firestore.firestore()
        let userDB = store.collection(userPath)
        
        
        //Query the DB for the given username. If we find that username, then throw an error
        userDB.whereField("username", isEqualTo: username).getDocuments(){ (querySnapshot, err) in

            if let error = err{
                print("Error querying DB: \(error)")
                return
            }
            
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents{
                if document.exists{
                    // these returns return from the block, not the containing function
                    return
                }
            }
            // no matching user found 
            //set data if no document exists
            userDB.document("\(UUID().uuidString)").setData(
                [
                    "username":username,
                    "password":password
                ]
            )

        }
        // code placed here runs before the getDocuments completion block
        // so nothing here can depend on the result of the get
    }
```

Comment: is there a way to make certain lines of code wait for something else to complete before executing?

Comment: Also, are there any good resources you could recommend to me that can help me understand how to design code asynchronously? I understand the concept(both pieces of code execute at the same time, but a DB query takes longer to finish than a simple if statement), but I would like to know how that fact should change my programming

Comment: @BruceJagid - do you mean, is there *another* way?  The common way in swift is pass a completion block which runs after the async task. The way we forced the user create to run after the get was to put the create in the get's completion block.